# GraphQL query to get all single type pages using Strapi

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, strapi

I'm trying to figure out the best way to pull do a query of the new single types using GraphQL. I've been trying to create a "Group" type that uses a relation to multiple single types in the Strapi admin, this approach would be like querying a collection type with multiple articles something in it... but haven't been able to figure that solution out either. I was also thinking maybe there was a way to just query all and only single types, but couldn't find any reference to that too.

For reference, this is the only documentation I've found about the single types: https://strapi.io/blog/beta-19-single-types-uid-field

Any direction or help on how to get a list of single types from GraphQL would greater!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check the version of gatsby-source-strapi. I was running into the same issue and I had version 0.0.10 which was not working with singleTypes. I upgrade to 0.0.12 and I was able to view single types in Graphql